# NSIS define inside define

Tags: installation, nsis

Is it possible to create a define inside define in NSIS?

for example

`!define WORLD 'world'
    !define HELLO 'Hello ${World}' 
    detailPrint ${HELLO}`

Those lines of code don't work... Is there another way to make this happen?

Comment: of course, this is not working, I want to know if there is something similiar

Answer (score 2):

1. `DetailPrint` expects a single parameter, while expanding `${HELLO}` will result in 2 words "Hello world", resulting in the message

   > detailPrint expects 1 parameters, got 2.

   Surround the constant with single, double or back quotes.
2. `DetailPrint` can only be used inside a `Section`, if you tried exactly what you posted as a script, it should have tell you

   > Error: command detailPrint not valid outside Section or Function

The following minimal script works as you expect:

```
outfile "helloworld.exe"

!define WORLD 'world'
!define HELLO 'Hello ${World}'

Section
    detailPrint "${HELLO}"
SectionEnd
```